# Complex Analysis using logarithms

Tags: complex-analysis

> Compute $\log(8+15i)$.

The following is my work:

$\log(8+15i)= \ln|17| + i \tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{15}{8}\right)+2\pi i k $, where $k$ is an integer.

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: This is correct, if by $\tan^{-1}15/8$ you mean the value in $(0,\pi/2)$. The value in $(\pi, 3\pi/2)$ is NOT correct.

Comment: @MPW: this answer is correct, but the work shown might give the wrong answer if the real part of the argument is not positive, for example, $\log(-8-15i)$. That is why I like to use $2\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)$ instead of $\tan^{-1}\left(\frac yx\right)$

Comment: @JesHuerta: was there a question, or did you just want verification?